# How to process stream data when KSQL server running in Headless mode?

Tags: apache-kafka, streaming, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I have to deploy KSQL on production server so I have changed interactive mode to headless mode. Created a SQL script to load all streams at container startup. Now I want to see stream data. How many ways are there to see those live streams like we can connect KSQL server to control center and achieve this. But I don't want to make a dependency like we need to buy enterprise edition of Confluent.
Please give your suggestions or inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KSQL (or [ksqlDB](https://ksqldb.io) to be technically correct) is an streaming analytics layer built on top of Apache Kafka. While this is mouthful and could means different things for different people -- in your particularly case it means that if you need to see the streams of data you can simply monitor the Kafka topics created by the streams/tables of your SQL script.

in ksqlDB, every stream and/or table that is backed by a continuous query flushes its results into a generated topic that contains a prefix (this is dictated by the `ksql.output.topic.name.prefix` configuration parameter) and the name of the stream/table. Just use any CLI tool (such as kafka-console-consumer, kafkacat, etc) to connect to the Kafka cluster and print the topic content.

Comment: I am not able to see topics for streams. For tables I can see topics on Kafka. If you want I can share my yaml files.

Comment: You should be able to see any topics that were created by a continuous query. In ksqlDB, there are 2 types of streams: the ones that wraps the topic sources and the ones that actually act upon existing streams. The ones that simply wrap the topic sources won't have any generated topic because they just wrap and thus the data is contained in the topic being wrapped. However, any stream reads data from another stream will have a generated topic for it. For example:

[sourceTopic] ---> [stream1] ---> [stream2]

In this case, you should have a new topic called "stream2" but not "stream1".

Comment: Thanks @Ricardo for your response. Need your help in my another issue I have created JDBCSink Connector to dump my events to DB which is working fine. Now my issue is related to time window. I have made a stream which is calculating events for last 1 hour and stored in DB. If I have some events for first hour then those will stored in DB and there are no events for next two hours. Now if I check in db it still shows the count for first hour but it has to show count as 0 because there is no events for last hour. How we can achieve this?